# Iframe Resizing within Joomla K2

Tags: html, css, iframe, joomla3.0

Firstly apologies if I am asking a question that's been asked and answered... I'm just hitting my head against the wall here ...

So here is the URL for the issue:

http://thedligroup.no-ip.biz/thedligroup/k2/portfolio/item/16-jensen-world-travel-port

I am attempting to add an iframe for my personal website, of one of my clients websites.

And currently I have the iframe sized how I would like it, but I want to have it scaled to full view at those dimensions (w:600xH:350)

here is the css I used as well:

```
  `#iframe {
   width:600px;
   height:350px;
   -moz-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); 
   -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); 
   -o-transform: scale(1, 0.25);
   -ms-transform: scale(1, 0.25);
    transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); 
   -moz-transform-origin: top left;
   -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
   -o-transform-origin: top left;
   -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
   }`
```

And the iframe code I used is as follows:

```
        `<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.jensenworldtravel.com"></iframe>`
```

Any and all help is appreciated, first poster, long time lurker... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you do not want to scroll. This code can help you.

```
<iframe src="http://www.jensenworldtravel.com" scrolling="no" height="400" width="600" >
<div id="addcontent" style='width:600px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:400px;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;'>

</div>
</iframe>
```

As a result of this code into your CSS style you need to add.

```
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/7WRHM/1639/)

Comment: No, its not that I do not want the scroll, I just want the iframe to be scaled back so that the whole page can be scene in the iframe ... does that make sense?